# SharePoint Developer DashBoard

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-server, server-farm

Once we activate SharePoint Developer dashboard using powershell, up to what scope does it apply? Can we see the developer dashboard screen on every site in the farm?

And is it a correct thing to do on production servers just to check the performance?

Will it cause additional performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

The developer dashboard is activated on farm level

> (Get-SPFarm).PerformanceMonitor.DeveloperDashboardLevel = ”OnDemand”

It's pretty safe to use and should not call other performance issues.

Be aware that the DD might not be displayed on custom masterpages, depending on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When enabled in On mode, the Dashboard is viewable on all pages that use the default master page. It applies to all the sites in Farm.

When enabled, the Developer Dashboard appears by default on any page that uses the SharePoint Foundation 2010 master page or any page using a custom master page where the Dashboard control is included.

Developer Dashboard should not be activated on production servers.
Developer dashboard should be enabled only when you see some unexpected behavior (delay in loading webpart etc) and want to see what part of page is taking more time.

Enabling it will surely affect performance of your SharePoint site since it will have to load the calculations.

For more details:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512745(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512745%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2dc839d6-6529-4891-a69f-3d4bc0c9c300/developer-dashboard-in-production-environment?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

**what scope does it apply?** It is farm level.

**Can we see the developer dashboard screen on every site in the farm?** it is enabled on all site collection in the farm but only **Site Collection Admin can see it.** Minimum permission required for the DD is Site Collection Admin

**is it a correct thing to do on production servers just to check the performance?** it is good thing to check the performance on the page, this will give which part of page consuming more time...a sql query or webpart or something else.

**Will it cause additional performance issues?** their is no impact on the performance, this tool already in sharepoint but not visible and loaded all the time when page loaded to record the timings.

Even if you are worried then enable it as onDemand.